# Subversion (Svn) Propfind 405 error

Tags: apache-2.2, svn

Asked the following over at stackoverflow.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016868/subversion-svn-propfind-405-error/2017121
```

They said you may be able to help.

I am brand new to subversion and have been told that this is the best thing since sliced bread. I have tried google and I am just drawing blanks on what is wrong and have tried multiple different suggestions. I get the following error

The Location information has been specified incorrectly.

svn: Propfind of '/svn': 405 Method not allowed (http://IPADDRESS) with IPADDRESS being the IP of my server.

I get this when I try to log in through Zend Studio. I use the following to try to login url http://IPADDRESS/svn/ username: fakeuser password: fakepassword

I believe that the issue is around this file because of the error "Location Information has been specified incorrectly". This file is included in the httpd.conf file. I have restarted apache and there are not errors when restarting apache.

```
<Location /project1>
   DAV svn
   SVNPath /home/jhughes/project1
   AuthzSVNAccessFile /home/jhughes/.svn-policy-file
   AuthName "SVN Repositories"
   AuthType Basic
   AuthUserFile /home/jhughes/.svn-auth-file
   Satisfy Any
   Require valid-user
</Location>
```

I have spent a few hours on this and cannot get it. So any help is appreciated and I will for sure give someone the point.

I am not using a proxy server. I am using the IP address of the server because I have multiple domains on the server and thought this may be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Ops, maybe I have lost something, but if your Location is "/project1" why access http://IPADDRESS/svn/?

I just paste your Location conf snippet here (ubuntu karmic), create the repo and user and authz files and everything worked here under "http://IPADDRESS/project1"

Your .svn-auth-file hasnt errors?

Through ordinary browsers it works?

Something happens on apache logs?

Answer (score -1):

I've just finished battling with the same error message. It turns out that for some of the svn methods it is important to make the distinction between ServerName (which needs to be the actual server name) and ServerAlias (that will be a name of your choosing for catching domains and subdomains you set up in your DNS.

So

```
<VirtualHost *:443>                                                             
    ServerName svn.mydomain.net   
    ...
 </VirtualHost>
```

Will give the error:

```
svn: E175002: Unexpected HTTP status 405 'Method Not Allowed' on '/svn'

svn: E175002: Additional errors:
svn: E175002: PROPFIND request on '/svn' failed: 405 Method Not Allowed
```

But if you set up your virtual host correctly with the ServerName matching your `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts` files, the error will no longer appear.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>                                                             
    ServerName mydomain.net                                                  
    ServerAlias svn.mydomain.net   
    ...
 </VirtualHost>
```